# Volume related to rotating over y=-1

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the following curves about the line y=−1.

$y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$

[Visual of ^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSUM6.png)

What I got so far was $\int_{0}^1 2\pi (y+1) (y^2-y^\frac{1}{2}) dy$, when I solve it though I get $-\frac{29\pi}{30}$. This is the wrong answer can someone tell me where I did something wrong? Because I can not tell.

Comment: It looks like you just flipped two terms around. $y^2<\sqrt y$ when $0<y<1$. Otherwise, it numerically looks like the right answer (unless I'm missing something as well).

Comment: You are in limits $0 \leq y \leq 1$ where $y^2 \leq \sqrt y$ so the shell size should be $\sqrt y - y^2$ as mentioned in previous comment. Rest of the working is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What doobdood said was right all I had to do was changed $y^2-y^\frac{1}{2}$ to $y^\frac{1}{2} - y^2$, where the answer to the question would be $\frac{29\pi}{30}$ if the correct answer.
Thank you Doobdood.